# How to get specific string from array result

Tags: php

```php
$userinfo = {"userdata":{"usertarget":{"id":12345,"name":"John Doe","status":"user"}}}
```

for example, that was the result i got and call it as `userinfo`, and now how can i find the specific word from `userinfo` such as like `"name":"John Doe"` and then `echo` it

like

```php
$userinfo = {"userdata":{"usertarget":{"id":12345,"name":"John Doe","status":"user"}}}
$find = ... //find "name":"John Doe" from $userinfo
echo $find;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: first you need to decode your json json_decode($userinfo, true) to array

Comment: i tried
$find = json_encode($userinfo);
echo $find->userdata->usertarget->name;
but it echoing nothing